# PHP: run shell_exec or system as sudo?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a few commands I need to invoke from my PHP web application that can only run as `sudo`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php says (in the comments) that I can do the following:

```
system('echo <password> | sudo -u root -S <command>');
```

It doesn't work. I'm trying to do a `groupadd`, `useradd`, etc. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a user to the sudo list and have it not prompt for a password for a certain program... edit your /etc/sudoers file as such:

```
Cmnd_Alias BUNDLE = /usr/bin/bundle

deploy  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:BUNDLE
```

Where deploy is the username and /usr/bin/bundle is the path the program that I want to access without password.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Take a look at this: http://shayanth.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-execute-sudo-shell-command-in.html. It suggests to use `$outPut = shell_exec("echo password_for_the_user | sudo -S command_to_execute");` -- also not working for me. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably that would only work if the user php runs as (apache, nobody or something else, depending on the apache config) has sudo enabled without password for that command.  Which is rather unlikely, given the wide, yawning security hole it would open.